# Magento started showing PHP language errors since I downloaded the blank theme using Connect

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I used the Magento Connect downloader to install the blank theme extension, but I did not switch to it as I was unable to access any-page anymore. Instead, it started showing php errors for front-end and Magento generated security errors for admin.

---

Frontend Error:

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function **toHtml()** on a non-object in **D:\xampp\htdocs\newpinch\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php** on **line 529**

---

Admin error on Log-in:

**There has been an error processing your request**

*Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.*

Error log record number: 1608724822

---

[Link to the theme extension I installed.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/518/blank-theme)

I didn't even change the theme from the default, can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong. I just installed the theme and then clicked on "Return to admin" in Magento Connect but it was unable to go instead started refreshed the Magento Connect page, only this time without any CSS styling. The only page that still appears correctly is the admin log-in page.

Please help me, I have already tried the forums at magentocommerce.com and their community sucks. 0 views & 0 replies. please help...

Comment: You should at least provide which magento version you have installed

Comment: You get out of a community what you put into it.

Comment: I'm sorry. The version is 1.3.2.4

I installed this one because the tutorial I was following was using this one and I wanted to make sure I don't run into errors. Looks like I did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this error after update Magento from 1.4.0 to 1.4.1.

For fixed needs in file page.xml

change string

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" />
```

to

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but where is this file...I just started with Magento. I'm using 1.3.2.4

Thanks!

Comment: /public_html/<site_name>/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/page.xml

Answer (score 0):

Without further info I guess you have installed Magento 1.4.1.0 (which is the latest version) but the blank theme your link points to says clearly **Compatibility: 1.3**

So most likely thats the cause of your error. That the theme files aren't compatible with the 1.4.1.0 version.